# Perl Script for changing commented llines from c++ to Ansi C style

Tags: scripting

I am having a multiple C source files. In those files, comments are used in C++ style(i.e //). These i want to change in c style(/*  */). Instead of changing it manually, is there any scripts to do this. If any,let me know, i will be thank full to you.

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty solution is `sed 's=//\(.*\)$=/*\1 */=`.

This solution is not robust because `//` may occur inside strings and even other comments.

A robust solution needs a (partial) C lexical analyzer. However, one can argue that there is no real solution to this problem because these two types  of comments are incompatible.

Consider this example from http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2013-04/msg00310.html.

```
int x = 5 //* strange construction */ + 5
      + 5;
```

`x` will be 6 in old-style ANSI C, but 10 if the compiler accepts '//' comments.